# html overflow : auto not working on IE

Tags: html, overflow

I have a div which have a literal which is filled at runtime. The overflow of that div is set to auto but still in IE its showing the contents. However the scrollbar is also appearing but the content is going beyond div and scroll is not working.
Any idea?

Comment: Please post some sample code.

Comment: auto is not well defined by CSS2.1 (see here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow).  Have you tried scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set the containing DIV to "position: relative"? See this as a reference:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/

Answer (score 0):

Without some example code it's not really possible to tell where the problem is.

Does the div has a set height and/or width? `overflow:auto` only works when the rendering engine knows when it should start displaying scrollbars.