# Leaflet Layer Control - Overflow not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with a layer control panel that is too long. To gain access to all layers I placed the following code in the .html file.

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
      .leaflet-control-layers {
        max-height: 800px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
...<rest of document>...
</body>
```

This works fine with Chrome, Firefox and Safari and allows scrolling through the list and therefore access to all layers. Sadly it doesn't work with Internet Explorer. Although it is possible to scroll through the layer control panel also on IE it is not possible to select a layer. As soon as I click on a layer, the list scrolls back to the top, no layer gets selected.

How can I achieve a layer control panel with automated overflow that works also on Internet Explorer? Preferably the solution should be placable as `CSS` in the file as done above.

Comment: Have a look at these links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079361/html-overflow-auto-not-working-on-ie
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692311/overflow-auto-not-working-in-ie-with-100
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755369/overflow-auto-inside-a-div-not-working-in-ie